# Memory Caching of Data from Disk

Tags: caching, memory-management, operating-system, cpu-architecture

I've always known that main memory caches data read from files on disk, but I have trouble reconciling this with the typical memory usage of a program, as shown in this diagram:[image]

If I use `fread` or `fgetl` on a very large file `2010Stats.txt`, on which segment of the above diagram does memory cache data from disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the address-space of your process.  Each process has its own virtual memory address-space.  Unless you `mmap` a file, its data only appears in your process's memory when copied there by a `read` system call or equivalent.  (C stdio / iostream functions will be implemented on top of system calls like that.)

The disk-cache is managed by the OS kernel, which has to keep track of how the physical pages of memory are used, as well the virtual address mappings of every process.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that when you open a file, it is not necessarily the case that its entire contents are read into primary memory (unless I'm mistaken). Also worth noting are file handles, which, I suspect, reside on the process's heap somewhere - notable because you can indeed run a particular process out of memory by opening too many files.

Comment: @jbowman: In POSIX, a file descriptor is just an integer.  The data is all inside the kernel, where the kernel can trust it.  Same for Windows file handles.  A stdio `FILE *` does point to data inside the process, on the heap.  stdio uses small i/o buffers to avoid calling out to the OSes `read` and `write` system calls too often, and that's most of the per-`fopen` memory usage, I think.

Comment: So `myChar=fgetc(myStream)` only consumes 1 or 2 bytes in the *virtual* address space of my program, but the page storing `myChar` part of `2010Stats.txt`, which is about 8 KB in size, would now be brought into *physical* memory. A copy of this page is neither in the *virtual* address space of the user program nor the kernel...but it resides in *physical* memory? What OS process or "construct" can I look up to find out more about this caching process? I'm just trying to understand it within the memory framework I'm already familiar with.

Comment: @Tosh: Don't worry about the kernel's virtual address space.  Linux for example uses the upper 1/4 of virtual address space to map all of physical memory.  (On a 32bit system with more than 1G of RAM, it can't map all of physical memory at once: those pages are HIGHMEM IIRC.)  Just assume that the kernel does a good job of using physical pages that aren't needed for anything else as [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache).  When you call `mmap`, it can map those pages into your address space.  When you call `read`, it copies from those pages into your existing pages.

Comment: `myChar=fgetc(myStream)` implies that `myStream` is already open, so the stdio buffer is already allocated.  If the buffer isn't empty, then no system call happens.  No new memory is allocated, but the contents of some allocated memory changes.  If you wrote `int myChar = ...`, the function containing that might have to allocate `myChar` on the stack (if it doesn't have enough free registers to keep it live).  The file data may not be in the kernel's page cache yet, so the kernel may have to page in the data from the file into the page cache.  Maybe replacing an old page.

Comment: @Tosh: pages are 4kiB in x86 and ARM, and many other architectures.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you - this is very helpful. Followup question if you don't mind: Say Program A just read the 24th character of `2010Stats.txt`, and so the OS has now brought the associated page into main memory as page cache. Now Program B, an independent but concurrent process, happens to read the 24th character of `2010Stats.txt` as well. Since the cached page doesn't belong to Program A, Program B's read will be much faster, because there's no page fault this time, correct? Just wanted to make sure this page cache can be freely "shared" or used by all programs this way.

Comment: @Tosh: That's right.  The whole point of the page cache is that it's global, maintained by the OS, not a private per-process thing.